# Using API to expose internal REST services

Tags: api, rest, wso2

I'm trying to expose an internal REST implementation via wso2.
here's the API definition

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="API" context="/api" hostname="http://toto.com" port="80">
   <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/{methodName}">
      <inSequence trace="disable">
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http uri-template="http://toto.com/1.0.1/api/{uri.var.methodName}" method="GET|POST|PUSH|PUT|DELETE"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

I'm only tying to relay the methodName.
I'm pretty new to wso2, still I can't find what's wrong here ?
Thanks for any help or links.

Comment: Are you using APIM or ESB?

Comment: using APIM in this case

Answer (score 0):

Well I had to remove port and hostname from the api definition in order to make it work.
Not sure why but if it can help